# RPLIDAR A1 not sampling as fast as expected with python

Tags: python, serial-port, ros, lidar, slam

using the **A1 lidar** from **RPLIDAR**, and one of the python3 libraries that implement the SDK (in my case it's rplidar library), I couldn't get the lidar to sample the points as fast as the documentation suggests, i.e. it should reach 8000 points/sec and i'm at the maximum at 1000points/sec (5.5Hz*170), and that's really not enough for my usage (creating a 3D mesh from pointcloud)

the code I use to check speed is here:
https://github.com/SkoltechRobotics/rplidar/blob/master/examples/measure_speed.py
and the code to get the number of measurements per scan is the sample in the [readme](https://github.com/Roboticia/RPLidar/blob/master/README.md).

I get this results:

[image]

Does anyone know how to implement the full sampling rate of the lidar, from the Python API?
I work either from raspberry or Windows. If the solution could be 100% python it would be really best.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the python libraries are aging for this device.

Try maxing out your motor speed and using express (i.e. compressed) mode.  The express mode allows more measurements across the same 115200 baudrate connection and the scan rate is directly correlated to the motor speed (automatically).

- To set the motor speed to the max, try adding `import rplidar` at the top and `lidar.motor_speed = rplidar.MAX_MOTOR_PWM` before `lidar.iter_scans()`
- To use express/compressed mode, call `iter_scans` like `iter_scans(scan_type='express')`.
- You can also try adding `min_len=100` to have iter_scans yield less often with more data and `max_buf_meas=False` to avoid dropping the data and receiving the "too many bytes in the input buffer" message that's visible in your screenshot.

(I'd also recommend trying it without the print statement inside the loop unless you definitely want to monitor it live.)

**Full Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''Measures sensor scanning speed'''
import rplidar
import time

PORT_NAME = '/dev/ttyUSB0'

def run():
    '''Main function'''
    lidar = rplidar.RPLidar(PORT_NAME)
    old_t = None
    data = []
    try:
        print('Press Ctrl+C to stop')
        
        lidar.motor_speed = rplidar.MAX_MOTOR_PWM
        for _ in lidar.iter_scans(scan_type='express',min_len=100,max_buf_meas=False):
            now = time.time()
            if old_t is None:
                old_t = now
                continue
            delta = now - old_t
            print('%.2f Hz, %.2f RPM' % (1/delta, 60/delta))
            data.append(delta)
            old_t = now
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stoping. Computing mean...')
        lidar.stop()
        lidar.disconnect()
        delta = sum(data)/len(data)
        print('Mean: %.2f Hz, %.2f RPM' % (1/delta, 60/delta))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, indeed the mode "express" improves the number of points by 2 (i got 2230 points/sec around). However the lidar.motor_speed trick seems to do nothing, or is not taken into account.

Comment: The lastests SDK mentions a "boost" value for the scan_mode argument that could reach even more sampling rate, but it does not seem to be implemented in the library

Comment: Different revisions of the A1 support different rates.  See this from the manual:  "R1andR2 models only support the radar 2k timespersecond ranging frequency.R3andR4 models need to update the firmware to 1.24 to support 8k times persecond ranging frequency"  on page 4 https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/4010/4010_datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Full Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 '''Measures sensor scanning speed'''
import rplidar
import time

PORT_NAME = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
def run():
    '''Main function'''
    lidar = rplidar.RPLidar(PORT_NAME)
    old_t = None
    data = []
    try:
        print('Press Ctrl+C to stop')
        lidar.motor_speed = rplidar.MAX_MOTOR_PWM
        for _ in lidar.iter_scans(scan_type='express', min_len=100, max_buf_meas=False):
            now = time.time()
            if old_t is None:
                old_t = now
                continue
            delta = now - old_t
            print('%.2f Hz, %.2f RPM' % (1/delta, 60/delta))
            data.append(delta)
            old_t = now
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stoping. Computing mean...')
        lidar.stop()
        lidar.disconnect()
        delta = sum(data)/len(data)
        print('Mean: %.2f Hz, %.2f RPM' % (1/delta, 60/delta))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please *format* your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, indeed the mode "express" improves the number of points by 2 (i got 2225 points/sec around). However the lidar.motor_speed trick seems to do nothing, or is not taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently ran into the same issue as you for my project : I tried both [Roboticia's fork](https://github.com/Roboticia/RPLidar) of the library you used, and [PyRPlidar](https://github.com/Hyun-je/pyrplidar).

PyRPlidar turned out to provide a little more readings while being python only, but still not enough to rival the C++ examples provided by slamtec / the ROS wrapper they have.

However, I found this [library](https://github.com/thehapyone/FastestRplidar), Fastest Rplidar that did the trick. It's essentially a wrapper around the C++ SDK that was built using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). The author talked about it in a [blog post](https://thehapyone.com/a-fast-rplidara2-python-library-for-the-raspberry-pi/).

The only problem for me was that it was only compiled for ARM (Raspberry Pi), but I was able to compile it for Linux easily following the instructions. You could use it pretty much as is for your Raspberry pi needs, and compile it for Windows to have a cross platform and C++ like performant solution.

Comment: thanks, but i couldn't understand from the doc if this lib need to be run the "setup.py install" because just cloning the code on my raspberry doesn't work